# Selecting only the subset from set of sets in python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the superset(if there is any for any set in my set of sets) and return only the subsets from the set of sets. I have written the below code, but it is taking long time for execution since i am handling large dataset, could someone suggest an other option for this.

For example, if i have a set of frozensets like this

```
skt = {{D},{E,D,M},{E,M}}
```

I need an output like

```
skt = {{D},{E,M}}
```

My code is,

```
for item in skt.copy():
    for other_item in skt.difference([item]):
        if item >= other_item:
            skt.remove(item)
            break
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the subsets"?  Do you mean you only want the sets that are a proper subset of some other set in the set?

Comment: Sorry, i just updated it. Anyways, explaining here. In my set of sets, i need to remove the supersets, if there is any for some other set in my set. Basically i am looking for minimal sets.

Comment: @Jeeva what's the expected output for something like: `{{D,F,E}, {D,F,E,M}, {E,M}}`

Comment: @AdamSmith If you run the code, the output is `{{D,E,F}, {E, M}}`.

Comment: you can simply use `item & skt` for find same subset ! so use it in your code !

Comment: Yes. Exactly it should be {{D,F,E}, {E, M}}

Comment: @Kasra could you please explain.. I am not getting that.

Comment: In other words... { x ∈ skt : (∄ y ∈ skt : x ⊃ y) }

Comment: Yeah. Correct. That's why i should return both in my output. Thats fine i am not confused with the output. My requirement is to remove the supersets and return only the minimal sets. What i am looking for is a better way to iterate may be, since my frozensets compare with every other for finding the superset. It is taking long time when it comes to handle large dataset.

Comment: I figured you knew what you're trying to do, but *we* were confused about the objective :)

Comment: @Jeeva see this link : http://www.python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php

Comment: Yes Chris. Thats correct, in other words. { X ∈ skt : (∄ y ∈ skt : y ⊄x)

Comment: Since we're talking about optimization, can you give us a sense of the scales you're dealing with - how many sets are there, what's a typical size for each set, and how many unique elements are there? (It's the ratios between these quantities that I'm interested in.)

Comment: Chris, i am handling a set of frozenset which has 70k frozensets in it.

Comment: That number isn't useful by itself... can you answer the other questions?

Comment: Ok. Totally its 70k frozensets. And each frozenset has different number of elements ranging from 1 to 15. But i am not able to find the unique elements since my dataset differs in my experimentation.

Comment: Here's a paper that addresses a very related problem http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~savnik/drafts/settrie0.pdf though I guess it would still lead you to a quadratic runtime.

Answer (score 3):

At least a minor optimization can be done: don't copy a set, but rather create a new one:

```
newset = set()
for x in skt:
   if not any(y < x for y in skt):
      newset.add(x)
```

Or in one line:

```
newset = set(x for x in skt if not any(y < x for y in skt))
```

**UPDATE:**

You can pre-calculate for each element the set of sets containing that element, and after that check each set only against the sets containing at least one of its elements:

```
setsForElement = defaultdict(set);
for s in skt:
    for element in s:
        setsForElement[element].add(s);

newset = set(s for s in skt if not any (setForElement < s for element in s for setForElement in setsForElement[element]))

# last line is equal to:
newset = set();
for s in skt:
    good = True;
    for element in s:
        if any(setForElement < s for setForElement in setsForElement[element]):
            good = False;
            break;

    if good:
        newset.add(s);
```

It may save you some time depending on your dataset. Of course in worst case (for example if your dataset is a [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of some set), the complexity will be again O(N^2) set comparisons. Or thinking of it, it can be even worse than straight algorithm because you may check the same set multiple times.

Comment: The copy should be O(N) while the `for` loops are O(N^2), isn't it? That mean's that your code shouldn't perform better than the original for large N. It might save memory, though.

Comment: @hennes I understand that, that's why I wrote *"At least"*.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding that

*For a list L of sets, return the sets with no superset in L*

```
skt = {{D},{E,D,M},{E,M}}
out = {{D}, {E,M}}
```

*and*

```
skt = {{D}, {E,G}, {E,H}, {D,E,F}, {E,F,G}}
out = {{D}, {E,G}, {E,H}, {D,E,F}}
```

if that's correct then (in my head and I may be wrong) the worst case always forces you to check all the pairs. You could do improvements, like don't iterate elements that have already been deleted. Or check each pair only one, and do it in both directions, and update accordingly. A itertools.product may be useful, but again, it doesn't update itself so when you delete an element, then I'm not sure what would be efficient.

A code a bit more optimized may be:

```
skt = {frozenset({1}), frozenset({1,2,3}), frozenset({2,3}), frozenset({4}), 
       frozenset({5,7}), frozenset({5,8}), frozenset({5,6,7}), 
       frozenset({6,7,8})}

newset = set()

def check(elem):
    to_delete = []
    ret = True
    for y in skt:
        if elem > y:
            to_delete.append(elem)
            ret = False
            break
        if y > elem:
            to_delete.append(y)
    for d in to_delete:
        skt.remove(d)
    return ret  

while skt:
    checking = skt.pop()
    if check(checking):
        newset.add(checking)
```

Comment: This approach seems more efficient than mine, can you explain why we are using that variable ret = True and ret = False??

Comment: And If i am not wrong, this code has to be updated. I am getting key error, when the 'elem' is deleted since we are returning True from the function for all cases. I tried to return 'ret' value, but in that case, after skt.remove(d),code execution is not going to return statement at all and so again i am getting the key error(which means the element is not present). Any help?

Comment: @Jeeva yeah, you are right, ``return True`` was wrong, it should be ``return ret`` [fixed]. I copied a second-to-last code iteration, my bad. Anyway, now when the elem is deleted it returns False so no key error should happen.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is essentially the same as yours, but it runs in order of ascending cardinality. The advantage could be significant, depending on your data (if there are some small sets that can knock out a lot of others in the early iterations).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def foo(skt):

    # Index the sets by cardinality
    index = defaultdict(lambda: set())
    for s in skt:
        index[len(s)].add(s)

    # For each cardinality i, starting with the lowest
    for i in range(max(index.keys()) + 1):

        # For each cardinality j > i (because supersets must be larger)
        for j in range(i + 1, max(index.keys()) + 1):

            # Remove j-sized supersets
            for y in [y for y in index[j] if any(y >= x for x in index[i])]:
                index[j].remove(y)

    # Flatten the index
    return set(x for xs in index.values() for x in xs)
```